# ASP.NET : xmldatasource displays string but nor the string variable

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have an an aspx file and I am having trouble using xmlDatasource and repeaters here is my code

```
<asp:xmldatasource runat="server" XPath="bookstore/genre[@name='fiction']" Id="XmlSource" data="<% x; %>">
 <data>
 <bookstore><genre name='fiction'><book ISBN='0000000000'><title>Secrets of Silicon Valley</title><price>12.95</price><chapters><chapter num='1' name='Introduction' /></chapters></book></genre></bookstore>
 </data>
 </asp:xmldatasource>

 <asp:Repeater
    DataSourceID="XmlSource"
    runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <h1><%# XPath ("book/title") %></h1>
          <b>Price:</b>
          <%# XPath ("book/price") %>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

It works just fine when I use it like this i.e. when I directly write the xml string inside the data object.

But when I store it in variable and use it it doesn't work. any idea how to make this happen

Here is what I am trying to do

```
string x = "<bookstore><genre name='fiction'><book ISBN='0000000000'><title>Secrets of Silicon Valley</title><price>12.95</price><chapters><chapter num='1' name='Introduction' /></chapters></book></genre></bookstore>";
<asp:xmldatasource runat="server" XPath="bookstore/genre[@name='fiction']" Id="XmlSource">
 <data>
 x;
</data>
</asp:xmldatasource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the XmlDataSource as in your example, but keep it empty in your markup:

```
<asp:xmldatasource runat="server" XPath="bookstore/genre[@name='fiction']" Id="XmlSource">
</asp:xmldatasource>
```

And then set the `Data` property in your code behind:

```
XmlSource.Data = @"
<bookstore>
 <genre name='fiction'>
  <book ISBN='0000000000'>
   <title>Secrets of Silicon Valley</title>
   <price>12.95</price>
   <chapters>
    <chapter num='1' name='Introduction' />
   </chapters>
  </book>
 </genre>
</bookstore>";
```